# Import Sequelize models back into database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I lost a Postgres installation. I thought it was no big deal because I had a directory full of Sequelize models. I can't find anything on google about how to get those models back into a new instance of Postgres.

I've seen reference to `sequelize.sync()` but, after adding that to each model, and trying to run the model (via node), it doesn't appear that it's updated my DB.

I'm sure it's possible. I really don't want to recreate all the schemas by hand. I really thought Sequelize was a lot like Rails/Django in that you could create models in code, and then just create a db based on those models.